# Pine Script Strategy - How to set a simultaneous STOP exit for 100% and TAKE exit for only 50%?

Tags: pine-script

I am entering a trade...

```
if (enterLong and strategy.position_size == 0)
    strategy.entry("Long", true)
```

This works as expected and enters when I want it to. But from here I would like to have a couple different exits:

- If hit the INITIAL STOP -> Get out of the trade 100%
- If hit the FIRST TAKE -> Get 50% out of the trade, move the STOP to break even, and move the SECOND TAKE to new condition

Currently, I have a *sort of* working version of this...

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size == initial_size)
    strategy.exit("LT1", limit=longTakePrice, qty_percent=50)
    strategy.close("Long", when=low<longStopPrice)
else
    if (strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size < initial_size)
        strategy.exit("LS2", stop=entryPrice)
        strategy.close("Long", when = takeCondition)
```

This *mostly* works, except the `close()` functions don't trigger until the next candle (instead of when the condition is met), and usually has significant (unrealistic) slippage.

I've tried the following...

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size == initial_size)
    strategy.exit("LT1", limit=longTakePrice, qty_percent=50)
    strategy.exit("LS1", stop=longStopPrice)
```

But this doesn't work. Instead, when `LS1` is hit, it only sells 50% of the position. Swapping the order of the statements doesn't work either.

**Edit 1:**

It makes no difference to add `qty_percent=100` to the stop exit.

Comment: See https://www.tradingview.com/script/tWS24Z2K-Two-level-TP-TrailStp-exits-example/

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size == initial_size)
    strategy.exit("LT1", limit=longTakePrice, stop=longStopPrice, qty_percent=50)
    strategy.exit("LS1", stop=longStopPrice)
```